# How to make this script actually stop when canceled?

Tags: vbscript

I've got a working script, but if the user launches it and then aborts with the cancel button the script generates the prescribed folders in whatever directory file explorer opens to. Obviously that's not good. I need the script to stop if the user cancels, but I have no idea how to do that?

Here's the code:

```
' 26Apr2015 jkw -- q&d

Option Explicit

Dim g_fso:  Set g_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tgt: tgt = BrowseFolder("M:\MarcStone Bids", False)


Dim subdirs:  subdirs = Array(_
"Anchors",_
"Color",_
"Engineering",_
"Mold Drawings",_
"Plans and Specs",_
"Plans and Specs\Plans",_
"Plans and Specs\Specs",_
"Revisions and Cost Changes",_
"Shops",_
"Managing Documents",_
"Managing Documents\Accounting",_
"Managing Documents\Approvals",_
"Managing Documents\Bid Documents",_
"Transmittals"_
)

Dim subdir
For Each subdir in subdirs
    g_fso.CreateFolder(tgt & "\" & subdir)
Next

Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog )
' This function generates a Browse Folder dialog
' and returns the selected folder as a string.
'
' Arguments:
' myStartLocation   [string]  start folder for dialog, or "My Computer", or
'                             empty string to open in "Desktop\My Documents"
' blnSimpleDialog   [boolean] if False, an additional text field will be
'                             displayed where the folder can be selected
'                             by typing the fully qualified path
'
' Returns:          [string]  the fully qualified path to the selected folder
'
' Based on the Hey Scripting Guys article
' "How Can I Show Users a Dialog Box That Only Lets Them Select Folders?"
' http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jun05/hey0617.mspx
'
' Function written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    Const MY_COMPUTER   = &H11&
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

    Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
    Dim objPath, objShell, strPath, strPrompt

    ' Set the options for the dialog window
    strPrompt = "Select a folder in which to create subdirectories:"
    If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
        numOptions = 0      ' Simple dialog
    Else
        numOptions = &H10&  ' Additional text field to type folder path
    End If

    ' Create a Windows Shell object
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    ' If specified, convert "My Computer" to a valid
    ' path for the Windows Shell's BrowseFolder method
    If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        strPath = objFolderItem.Path
    Else
        strPath = myStartLocation
    End If

    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
                                              numOptions, strPath )

    ' Quit if no folder was selected
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        BrowseFolder = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Retrieve the path of the selected folder
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path

    ' Return the path of the selected folder
    BrowseFolder = objPath
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Help has this sample code. This is the line you need. `if (not objFolder is nothing) then`

```
function fnShellBrowseForFolderVB()
    dim objShell
    dim ssfWINDOWS
    dim objFolder

    ssfWINDOWS = 36
    set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 0, ssfWINDOWS)
            if (not objFolder is nothing) then
                'Add code here.
            end if
        set objFolder = nothing
    set objShell = nothing
end function
```

then `err.raise num` or `wscript.quit`

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an empty string when no folder has been selected, so...

```
....
tgt = BrowseFolder("M:\MarcStone Bids", False)
' If no folder selected, quit 
If tgt="" Then 
    Wscript.Quit 1
End If
....
```